# Deleting a managedObject from table but how to delete attached image?

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

i need to now how i can get an image reference from a managedobject. This is the delete part when a user swipes and press delete

```
            if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row 
            //
            let managedObject: NSManagedObject = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
//context.deleteObject(managedObject)//outcommented to test
print("moc \(managedObject)")// i can see the right image file id/name but i don't now how to get it<-------
            removeImage("5354B06C-CFCB-4845-BEC3-B4B4855D8A36")//hardcoded to test if removeImage works and it does

            do {
                print("deleted")
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }
```

To get my code to work i only need to get the imagename from managedObject. When i print("moc (managedObject)") i see the imagename in

```
moc <Appointments: 0x1740c8f10> (entity: Appointments; id: 0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://DE573499-064D-4840-819E-6ED2923E42CC/Appointments/p3> ; data: { appointmentImage = "C374341D-7256-4A67-B836-D82619A64AC8";
appointmentAmount = 258;
```

How should i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of casting the object as NSManagedObject, use your data model. If Appointments is your date model then try this,

```
let managedObject = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Appointments
removeImage(managedObject.appointmentImage)
```